# Getting least significant bit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to get the least significant `bit` of a `number` in JavaScript.

I have the following code:

```
let lsb = (parseInt("110", 2) & 0xffff);
```

By my understanding, the least significant bit of 110 is 1**1**0 as it is the right-most set bit.

However, the code above returns '6', which is the total value of `110` and not the least significant `bit`.

How can I get the least significant bit?

Comment: `& 0xffff` is neither a way to get the lowest set bit nor the lsb. It's just completely unrelated to both of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The least significant bit is the rightmost bit, not the rightmost bit that's set. To get that, AND with `1`.

```
let lsb = parseInt("110", 2) & 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was misunderstanding the meaning of the least significant bit.

Answer (score 14):

I take you at your example that you are looking for the lowest set bit, not the least significant bit

What you're looking for is a bit of a bitwise hack.

We can do this with some exploitation of the way negative numbers are represented (two's complement)

```
var lowestSetBit = (value) & (-value)
```

If you are actually looking for the least significant bit, then you can just mask on that bit

```
var leastSignificantBit = value & 1
```

Comment: `lowestSetBit` was extremely useful for me. Much faster than unrolling and quite elegant. Not a chance I would have thought of this on my own.

Comment: I believe `lowestSetBit` will return value instead of the bit.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit:

> least significant bit (LSB) is the bit position in a binary integer
>   giving the units value, that is, determining whether the number is
>   even or odd

So it's easy:

```
let lsb = parseInt("110", 2) & 1
```

or even this:

```
let lsb = parseInt("110", 2) % 2
```

Comment: You're missing the input radix 2.

Comment: The part of his original code that parses the integer uses base 2, so I think that's clear.

Comment: Why would he intentionally give the second argument to `parseInt` if that wasn't what he intended? Anyway, you believe what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the least significant bit of a number can easily be done by:

```
someNumber & 1
```

or in your specific case:

```
let lsb = (parseInt("110", 2) & 1
```

This works by *masking* every bit with a zero except for the least significant bit, which is &'d with that 1.

For example, let's have our input number be 21

```
21 & 1
```

Is the same as:

```
  10101
& 00001 
-------
  00001 // => returns 1 since the last bit is turned on
```